# Super object has no attribute '__getattr__' python, kivymd

Tags: python, android, kivy, pydroid

This is one of those questions I've looked everywhere for the answer and can't find it anywhere.

I can't access ids at all. I've printed the screen and the screen shows the ids I need but when I try to pull the ids I get key error ex ids['delete'] or no attribute ex. ids.delete

I've looked everywhere on stack overflow and other sites even looked into the kivy/kivymd docs but I still can't find the answer

It looks exactly like what others do to get the ids

I'm using Pydroid

```py
#pylint:disable=E1101
from __future__ import print_function

import os.path


from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivymd.uix.screen import Screen
from kivymd.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRectangleFlatButton
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField

from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

SCOPES = ['https://mail.google.com/']

creds = None
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
if os.path.exists('token.json'):
    creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
            'credentials.json', SCOPES)
    
        creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
    # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())
            

emailTextField = ''

class Screen1(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        

kv = """
ScreenManager:  
    id: scrn_mnger
    name: scrn_mnger
    Screen1:
        
<Screen1>:
    id: main_scrn
    name: 'main_scrn'
    MDTextField:
        id:'emails_to_delete'
        hint_text:'Enter Emails'
        icon_left:'email'
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.8}
        mode:'rectangle'
        width:800
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        id: 'delete'
        name: 'delete'
        text: 'Delete'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':.7}
        on_release: app.on_start()
        """


        
class Manager(MDApp):
    

    def build(self):
        
        self.screen = Builder.load_string(kv)
        return self.screen
    
    def on_start(self): 


        #This code bit here is the issue
        print(self.root.get_screen('main_scrn').ids.delete)
        #This code bit here is the issue

        try:

            service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)       
            
            
        
            messages = service.users().messages().list(userId='me', q='from:')
    
            if messages:
                messagesList = messages
            else:
                messagesList = []
                messageIDs = []
            
                for i in messagesList:
                        messageIDs.append(i['id'])
                        
                service.users().messages().batchDelete(userId='me', body={'ids':messageIDs}).execute()
        
       
        except HttpError as err:
            print(err)


def main():
    pass




        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Manager().run()
```

Error

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /storage/emulated/0/Documents/GoogleAPI/.kivy/logs/kivy_22-10-05_2.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.0.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.9.7 (default, Oct  6 2021, 01:34:26) 
[GCC 11.1.0]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/bin/python3"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 186 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [KivyMD      ] 1.0.2, git-38fe356, 2022-08-11 (installed at "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivymd/__init__.py")
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL ES 2" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <sdl2>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'OpenGL ES 3.2 V@0502.0 (GIT@3c44ec2e9d, I9dd863ea0e, 1602076608) (Date:10/07/20)'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Qualcomm'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Adreno (TM) 619'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 3, 2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 861, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 KeyError: 'delete'
 
 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
 
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/storage/emulated/0/Documents/GoogleAPI/quickstart.py", line 138, in <module>
     Manager().run()
   File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/app.py", line 949, in run
     self._run_prepare()
   File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/app.py", line 944, in _run_prepare
     self.dispatch('on_start')
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 709, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "/storage/emulated/0/Documents/GoogleAPI/quickstart.py", line 99, in on_start
     print(self.root.get_screen('main_scrn').ids.delete)
   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 864, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'
```

Comment: Actually the root of the problem is the first error `File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 861, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 KeyError: 'delete'`. What do you expect from this line `print(self.root.get_screen('main_scrn').ids.delete)`? What is `.delete` for, obviously you cannot do that

Comment: @buran ,  ids.delete is an id path I made in the kv string. I accessed the screen which has objects and one of the objects is delete. I really want to access the 'emails_to_delete' text which is giving the same errors

Answer (score 0):

The `ids` in your `kv` should not be strings. Just remove the enclosing quotes from the `id` definitions.

Comment: I removed the string in the ids. I'm getting the same errors. Is there any chance it's because I'm doing it on phone instead of pc/laptop?

Comment: Nevermind, it wants to work now, restarting the app after removing Id as string. Not sure what was really causing the issue